# Creating a Language Server for Eclipse Che

Tags: eclipse-che, language-server-protocol

I want to create a language server from Eclipse Che. But the Che conf video guide was not that helpful because the video quality is poor. Anyone know a tutorial or a guide to implementing our own language server using Eclipse Che?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the [LS-Sidecars](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/language-servers.html#ls-sidecars) guide on the Eclipse Che document if you are interested in the sidecar approach. [This tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/may/article5.php) may also help you.
I have also opened several Github issues for the problems that came across when I tried to do the same. [These](https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/11415) [issues](https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/11299) might also help you if you are using a sidecar approach.

Comment: Hi. Were you successful with this task? Could you share detailed steps on 1) how to create a FAT JAR 2) how to test it? 3) how to create a docker image with this FAT JAR 3) how to configure Eclipse Che to use this docker image? I would appreciate it if you could maybe create a GitHub repository or a BLOG describing all those steps.